# Creating Mobile view in Asp.net MVC using Kendo UI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-mobile

I have an asp.net mvc project based on bootstrap which almost all the views are responsive. However is not possible to make it responsive for two of them. That is the reason why I make these two views with jQuery Mobile. But because of some limitation i decide to create them with Kendo UI, with jQuery mobile i create viewName.mobile.cshtml and it works fine whenever i visit my web application with mobile device and it renders appropriate view correctly.

when i start using kendo UI I figured out it is somehow different. the question is : it is possible to implement my senario  with kendo UI?? or i should create kendo mobile application separately?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with jQuery Mobile, it will work with Kendo to. Try using the Kendo Mobile for ASP.NET MVC here: http://www.kendoui.com/server-wrappers/mvc/mobile.aspx